# Why I need to cast bitmap to image in one case and not in another?

Tags: c#, graphics

`Bitmap b = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(path);`  //needs casting

`..Graphics.DrawImage(b,x,y);` //does not need casting altough DrawImage accepts only type Image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Bitmap` is always an `Image`, but not every `Image` is a `Bitmap`; or in class terms:

```
public sealed class Bitmap : Image {...}
```

The method in the first is actually inherited from `Image` - it is *really* calling:

```
public static Image FromFile(string path)
```

, and you need to assert that it is a `Bitmap` to push it into a `Bitmap` variable. After all, it could be *another* supported type of `Image` - not just a bitmap. Presumably your `path` points to a bitmap-type image.

If you had:

```
Image img = Image.FromFile(path); // or var img = Image.FromFile(path);
...
Graphics.DrawImage(img,x,y);
```

then life would be clearer.

In the second case, it just wants an `Image` - *any* `Image` will do; `Bitmap` is fine...

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Bitmap.FromFile`, you are actually calling `Image.FromFile`. `FromFile` is not a static method of `Bitmap`, but because `Bitmap` inherits from `Image`, you can also access the `FromFile` method through `Bitmap`. The reason `Bitmap.FromFile` returns an `Image` is because it's the `FromFile` of the `Image` class.

`Image.FromFile` can load images of different types, for example of type `Bitmap`. You need to cast the result of `Image.FromFile` to `Bitmap` because the return type of `Image.FromFile` is always `Image`, regardless of the type of image loaded.

The reason you do not need to cast this for `Graphics.DrawImage` is because that method accepts any image type which descends from `Image`, which `Bitmap` is.